# VBA dynamic range problem. Elements in the vectors seem to change to 0 as I move on to the next node

Tags: excel, vba

```
Public Sub Project()
    
    Dim node As Integer
    node = count_node()
    
    'set up demand and horizon vector
    Dim demand() As Integer
    Dim horizon() As Integer
    ReDim demand(0 To node) As Integer
    ReDim horizon(0 To node) As Integer
    
    'generate demand and horizon value base on current node
    demand(node) = Int(50 + 450 * Rnd())
    horizon(node) = Int(10 + 30 * Rnd())
    Worksheets(2).Cells(node + 1, 1) = demand(node)
    Worksheets(2).Cells(node + 1, 2) = horizon(node)
    
    'set up stock vector and stock and their initials stock value
    Dim stock() As Integer
    ReDim stock(0 To node) As Integer
    stock(0) = 0
    Worksheets(2).Cells(1, 3) = stock(0)
    
    'set up production vector and initial production value
    Dim production() As Integer
    ReDim production(0 To node) As Integer
    production(0) = 3 * demand(0)
    Worksheets(2).Cells(1, 4) = production(0)
    
    'calculate stock at current node
    If node >= 1 Then
        stock(node) = stock(node - 1) + production(node - 1) - demand(node - 1)
    End If
    Worksheets(2).Cells(node + 1, 3) = stock(node)

    'calculate production at current node
    If node >= 1 Then
        If stock(node) < demand(node) Then
            production(node) = 3 * demand(node)
        Else
            production(node) = 0
        End If
    End If

    'update production values in the worksheet
    If node >= 1 Then
        Worksheets(2).Cells(node + 1, 4) = production(node)
    End If

    'generate demand rectangle at current node
    Worksheets(1).Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, horizon(node), 0, horizon(node), demand(node)).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbRed
    'generate stock rectangle at current node
    Worksheets(1).Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, horizon(node) + 20, 0, 20, stock(node)).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbGreen
    'generate production rectangle at current node
    Worksheets(1).Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, horizon(node) + 40, 0, 20, production(node)).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbBlue
    
End Sub

Public Function count_node() As Integer
    Dim aux As Integer
    aux = 1
    While Worksheets(2).Cells(aux, 1) <> Empty
        aux = aux + 1
    Wend
    count_node = aux - 1
End Function
```

the code create vectors and increase their length each time I run the code. But it seems like all the elements in the vectors change to 0 or empty as I move on to the next node.

Comment: Why have `demand` and `horizon` as arrays (FYI "vector" is not a term in VBA) if you only ever populate the last index in those arrays?

Comment: What's your expected output. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I'm fairly new to this. The reason is that I do not know how many times i want to run this code. I created a bottom in the excel sheet to execute the code. So I am trying to store everything inside the arrays so I can get access to them for other problems. I hope I understand your comment correctly.